# Using user input to access a variable in python

Tags: python, user-input

I'm trying to access the variables in my code using user input. I realize that the input will give me a string and not a variable, however I'm not sure how to fix this. I keep getting an error that reads:

```
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'email'
```

Here's the code. Any suggestions?

```
    class Person:
    def __init__(self, number, first, last, email):
            self.number =  number
            self.first = first
            self.last = last
            self.email = email



    p1 = Person('1', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address')
    p2 = Person('2', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address')
    p3 = Person('3', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address')
    p5 = Person('5', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address')
    p6 = Person('6', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address')
    p9 = Person('9', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address')
    p10 = Person('10', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address')


    user='p'+raw_input('Please Enter ID Number: ') 


    print(user.email)
```

Comment: What are you _really_ trying to do? If you're just playing around, that's one thing, but if anyone is going to be using this, you need to correct some major design flaws. Why `p1, p2, ... pn` (not even contiguous!) instead of a list? Why does your poor user have to select by ID number and not some other piece of information more easily known/remembered?

Comment: I'm working with a pre-existing database where the numbers are not contiguous. The individual users know their ID numbers as they are currently in use. I'm still pretty new to writing code, and this is for an academic project. I was told this would be an effective way to organize the data by a pier. What other piece of data would you suggest my users identify themselves with?

Comment: If everyone knows their ID I guess it's not so bad since you're leveraging an existing requirement instead of adding one. Really you should let them use some identifying piece of information that they already know, like their e-mail. I think any of it is fine as long as you try to use a method like one of Jordan Beasley's suggestions. Database ID's are for computers, not humans!

Answer (score 1):

use a dictionary! (while not the only way to achieve this, it is the correct way (imho at least))

```
people = dict(
    p1 = Person('1', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address')
    p2 = Person('2', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address')
    p3 = Person('3', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address')
    p5 = Person('5', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address')
    p6 = Person('6', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address')
    p9 = Person('9', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address')
    p10 = Person('10', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address')
)

print people["p"+raw_input("id")]
```

or use a list

```
people = [ Person('1', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address'), Person('1', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address'), Person('1', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address'),...]
print people[int(raw_input("Enter ID:"))]
```

or alter your `Person` class

```
class Person:
     people = {}
     def __init__(self,id,first,last,email):
         Person.people[id] = self
         ....
     @classmethod
     def getById(cls,id):
         try:
             return cls.people[id]
         except:
             return None

#then Later

p1 = Person('1', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address')
p2 = Person('2', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address')
p3 = Person('3', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address')
p5 = Person('5', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address')
p6 = Person('6', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address')
p9 = Person('9', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address')
p10 = Person('10', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address')

print Person.getById(raw_input("Enter ID:"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The dictionary does make more sense to use. However, I'm getting a syntax error when I try to run the new code. This is what it looks like:
p2 = Person('2', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address')
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: The problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It would be *way* better to store the`Person`instances in a list or dictionary. However you could do your way by looking the user entered variable name up in the`globals()`dictionary:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, number, first, last, email):
        self.number =  number
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.email = email

p1 = Person('1', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address1')
p2 = Person('2', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address2')
p3 = Person('3', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address3')
p5 = Person('5', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address5')
p6 = Person('6', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address6')
p9 = Person('9', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address9')
p10 = Person('10', 'first name', 'last name', 'email address10')

user = 'p' + raw_input('Please Enter ID Number: ')
try:
    user = globals()[user]
except KeyError:
    print('ID Number Unknown!')
    raise
print(user.email)
```

Answer (score -1):

Python is interpreting user as a string "pX" (where X is the input), rather than a variable pX. To fix this, you must evaluate the string as a variable. Try `print(eval(user).email)`. This will evaluate the string and return the Person object to which it is referring, and then grab the email attribute.

Comment: Booooo! Recommending `eval` and not even _mentioning_ the potential problems? -10! -100!

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist What are the potential problems with this?

Comment: use your code, then at the prompt enter `"format --force --no-prompt C:\"` thats what the potential problems are ... you can really hurt the system with eval ... if you really, really want to not use a better method,at least use the `locals()` or `globals()` dictionary instead  (that said I didnt downvote you either)

Comment: You know, I'm looking and looking for a resource explaining to a new programmer why you should never use `eval`, and I can't find one. The internet is now dominated with posts defending it against people like me. So instead I recommend you read [this](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/03/24/on-principle/). Just the first part. It's written by someone else from StackOverflow and gives (1.) a great example of how seasoned programmers feel seeing `eval` used wrongly and needlessly (like this answer), and (2.) shows a _great_ example of how a "safe" eval can go badly, badly wrong.

Comment: I appreciate the research. I guess I should stay away from eval then.